# please can anyone explain me why this permutation code is not working

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

please can anyone point out what I have done wrong this is code for permutation which stores all possible permutation of the small vector "vec" and then display it

```
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
vector <vector<int>> ans;

void permut(vector<int> &vec,int index){
if(index==vec.size()){
    ans.push_back(vec);
    return;
}
for (int i = index ;i<index;i++){
    swap(vec[i],vec[i+1]);
    permut(vec,index+1);
    swap(vec[i],vec[vec.size()]);
}

}

int main(){
    int n; cin>>n; 
    vector<int> vec(n);
    for(int i = 1;i<=n; i ++){
        vec[i-1]= i;
    }

    permut(vec,0);
    for (int j =0 ;j<ans.size();j++){
        for(int k = 0 ; k<vec.size();k++){
            cout<< vec[j]<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `vec[vec.size()]` will *always* be an out of bounds access. The last element you can access is `vec.size() - 1`.

Comment: or use `vec.back()`.

Comment: Notice there is [`std::next_permutation`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

Comment: [Edit] the question to include details on what is not working. I see multiple issues with the code, including with your output loop.

Comment: *just tell me everything you can that is wrong about this code* -- You didn't use `std::next_permutation` -- does that count?

Comment: `for(int i = 1;i<=n; i ++){ vec[i-1]= i; }` made me look twice. The idiomatic way to write that loop would be: `for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) vec[i] = i + 1;` - or better `std::iota(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 1);`

Comment: please can any one make changes to code and give i am new to recursion and i need a little help with this topic

Comment: @Anubis You say "_it's not working_" - but surely, _something_ is working? Remove everything not needed to exemplify the problem and ask a specific question.

Answer (score 0):

We have to run the for loop from `i = start` to `i = end` but you are running it from `i = index` to `i < index` which means your loop won't even run a single time.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector <vector<int> > ans;

void permut (vector <int> &vec, int start, int end){
    // base case
    if (start == end){
        ans.push_back(vec);
    } else {
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++){
            swap(vec[i], vec[start]);
            permut(vec, start + 1, end);
            swap(vec[i],vec[start]); //backtrack
        }
    }
    
}

int main() {
    int n; 
    cin >> n; 
    vector <int> vec(n);
    for (int i = 0;i < n; i++) {
        vec[i]= i + 1;
    }

    permut(vec, 0, n - 1);
    
    for (int j = 0; j < ans.size(); j++){
        for (int k = 0 ; k < vec.size(); k++){
            cout<< ans[j][k];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```